# Storyboard only shown in XML

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

All of the sudden my .storyboard file for my project only is shown in XML.

[image]

I am well aware of the "right click" -> "Open As" -> "Storyboard" option, however this does not appear. It only displays "None".

[image]

How do I fix this so I can open my storyboard as an actual storyboard?

Comment: Did you try quitting and re-opening Xcode ?

Comment: Yes that was my first option. I just restarted my mac also.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I suspect you are looking at Xcode's "Version Editor". Double check that you are not.

Version Editor enabled: [image]

Disable it.

---

Older Xcode versions:

Standard Editor: [image]

Version Editor: [image]

Comment: you were exactly right. I was in "Blame" mode, and of course it isn't going to show the name and time of what was committed in storyboard because storyboards are not linear text, **except** when it's viewed as XML. So Xcode was forcing my storyboard to open in XML when Blame mode was enabled. It makes sense when you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

select that storyboard -> now right click -> open As -> Interface Builder -Storyboard