# what happened to my storyboard in Xcode (swift 3)

Tags: xcode, storyboard

Only code shows up with the storyboard is how can I fix this. [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 8: Storyboard only shown in XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191517/xcode-8-storyboard-only-shown-in-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've somehow selected the version editor. If you press command-enter it should get rid of it and switch back to the standard visual IB editor.